# I am trying to get a element of a cretin class in python using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```py
import requests
r = response = requests.get('https://sky.lea.moe/stats/TheKatDev')
print(r.text)
```

I am trying to get an element of the class class="stat-value" with a request and I'm not sure how any help.  I'm tried a few things but none of it worked thank you for your help.

Comment: "Tried a few things" ... Such as...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use an XML or HTML parser (like BeautifulSoup) to get the value of that class.